# Unwrap a simple cylinder in 2.8

Tags: uv

I am trying to unwrap a basic cylinder to a picture wich has a size of 4096x1080px.

[image: open cylinder]

The UV map is supposed to look like the 64 faces side by side within the boundaries of the image.

Whatever I try - it never comes to that point. I tried to reset first and than unwrap, to reset and to follow active faces, to pack islands, etc.

There is one weird (I guess) thing: In pretty much every case the faces are rotated by 90° in the UV map. I don't know if this is related to something...

This is the standard map when I start from scratch and hit 2xU (All 64 faces are vertically squeezed into the boundaries) - I want exactly this - just horizontally:

[image: standart UV map]

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks and best.

Stefan

Comment: Can't reproduce, I get the expected result, try again on a clean file after factory reset, please.

Comment: Try to apply scale for the object (Object mode > object selected > Ctrl+A), then unwrap. Try also in Edit mode unpin all vertices on UV map and then unwrap again (though looks like they aren't pinned)

Comment: Thanks to the both of you. I did all that. I even tried to start from scratch (with default settings) - always with the same result. I also modified my cylinder (less faces, e.g.) - always the same: vertically aligned faces squeezed into boundaries of my picture. 

Is there an option to give one quad a pixel size? That could be a workaround: define the size (pixel perfect!) of one and than "follow quads"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this manually then mark a seam across the cylinder.

Select all the faces (<kbd>A</kbd>), and press <kbd>U</kbd> to unwrap.

Select **Cylinder Projection**.

Set the Direction to **Align to Object**.

To have the UV align with the Image (or the UV space) use **Scale to Bounds**

[image]

Comment: Awesome! That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to generate the UVs at the same time as you create your object. Just enable the *Generate UVs* box.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That solved the actual problem! Anyways - it would be helpful to have the possibility to do that later in the workflow.