# How can I make a texture follow the edges of my model?

Tags: shaders

I have a cylinder with a rounded tip, I have tried to rotate a checker texture by plugging texture coordinate generated into a mapping vector and then into the texture vector but still I have the texture make these arches across the sides of my cylinder, I would like the texture to wrap[image] around in a circle around my model

Comment: It does nothing, no matter what settings I change on the cylinder projection settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender use “Checker texture” as 3D texture, that is the reason for curvature on non-cubic shapes (like your).

You can imagine 3D texture like a volume of black and white cubes glued together in real world. If you shape this volume into your cylinder shape you get exactly that curvature on surface.

To wrap object by checker texture you should use UV socket in "Texture Coordinates" node (instead Generated). To make it works you have to unwrap your object firts (if it’s not already unwrapped automatically).

In your case try to unwrap existing object by “Cylinder Projection” see [tutorial here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144861/unwrap-a-simple-cylinder-in-2-8) ...

[image]

... or even better by “Follow Active Quad” type. See details in [Blender’s Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/uv/unwrapping/mapping_types.html?highlight=follow%20active%20quads) how to use it. Don't skip “Note” paragraph that is essential to get correct result (90°grid). Or here - [nicely explained](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/how-to-perfectly-align-uv-coordinates-automatically/74045#74045)

[image]

---

**Alternatively**

You can start from scratch ... add Cylinder object (that's unwrapped automaticaly). Since you choose UV (in Texture Coordinate node output) you get something like this.

[image]

If you go to "UV Editor" blender's layout, switch your object to edit mode and select all vertices. Grid appears in an UV Editor, so you can see how the mesh faces are unwrapped.

[image]

Add more loops (Ctrl+R)

[image]

Scale them to your shape. Go back to UV Editor and rearrange vertices to get more even grid for texture.

[image]

Comment: You can also use seams to slice up the model into easily unwrappable parts.